# How to install JudyArrays (C library) on Windows

Tags: c, windows, makefile, installation

I know it can sound as a pretty dumb question, but I do not have a great experience with installing downloaded libraries...

Anyhow I downloaded the source code of JudyArrays (which is a C library for a 256-trie for those who doesn't know it) from sourceforge and the installation instructions refers to the make command. I tried to download [this utility](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), but I can't get it work. Which is the correct target makefile? All I managed to get was:

```
"..path\Makefile.in":15: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

I tried googling for some help but didn't find anything, either I'm searching with the wrong query string or I'm the only dumb person in the whole planet that can't manage to install it...
Any help? Is there any simpler method?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Try switching the makefile between Windows-style and Unix-style linebreaks. I don't hold out much hope for it actually *working*, but IIRC you get this error from (certain builds of?) make when the linebreak style is wrong, so it might get you on to the next problem.

Answer (score 4):

Run your Visual Studio Command Prompt to get a cmd.exe with the proper paths set. cd into the `src` directory of the JudyArrays source code and run build.bat. This'll compile Judy and produce a .lib and a .dll and a Judy.h header file file you'll have to use in your projects as any other 3. party library.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but I get a huge amount of compiling errors, any clue? Examples:
    ..\JudyCommon/JudyPrivate.h: In function 'j__udySearchLeaf1':
    ..\JudyCommon/JudyPrivate.h:1556: error: 'uint8_t' undeclared (first use in this
 function)
    ..\JudyCommon/JudyPrivate.h:1556: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported
 only once
    ..\JudyCommon/JudyPrivate.h:1556: error: for each function it appears in.)
    ..\JudyCommon/JudyPrivate.h:1556: error: 'P_leaf' undeclared (first use in this
function)